# How do I Update Fi Star Health Questionnaire with New/Updated Questions?

Tags: fiware

I am trying to update the Fi-Star Health Questionnaire and am getting into some issue which I am not sure how to solve, tried already many different things.

Basically, everything looks very clear and straight forward, I updated the schema file we are using: dataLoadQuestionnaire_QSE_beta.csv in the HQSE_curl_tester directory

and then tried to run the load command (see below):

```
~/HQ/HQSE_code/HQSE_curl_Tester$ sudo curl -X POST -H "Content-Type :
multipart/form-data" --form stream="@dataLoadQuestionnaire_QSE_beta.csv"
127.0.0.1:8080/questionnaire.mng.rest/rest/ktek/questionnaire/load -v
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /questionnaire.mng.rest/rest/ktek/questionnaire/load HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type : multipart/form-data
> Content-Length: 20910
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------
b73558337a
324ed0
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Date: Mon, 29 Feb 2016 08:17:57 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
    {"Boolean":false}
```

I tried with using http 1.0, and tried to send different headers, but i seem to continue to get this connection to host left intact and boolean false, and so my live questionnaire doesn't get updated.

Need help with this.

Anyone knows how to work with Fi-Star Health Questionnaire SE and can help?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported.

Changing a live (active) questionnaire is not supported.
You have to create a new questionnaire.